# How does `-h` in `ls -lah` work in Unix?

Tags: unix, size, ls, human-readable

When I use `ls -la` and `ls -lah`, I seem to get different number for the same files.

```
gillin@mt:/home/vanilla/wmt-data/lm$ ls -lah *
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 68G Aug  5 03:57 lm.6gram.de.arpa.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 25G Aug  4 07:32 lm.6gram.fr.arpa.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 29G Aug  5 07:41 lm.6gram.ru.arpa.gz
gillin@mt:/home/vanilla/wmt-data/lm$ ls -la *
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 72726733721 Aug  5 03:57 lm.6gram.de.arpa.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 26482284407 Aug  4 07:32 lm.6gram.fr.arpa.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 vanilla vanilla 30777650366 Aug  5 07:41 lm.6gram.ru.arpa.gz
```

**Hows does the `-h` parameter round the size of the file?**

**Why is the `-lah` size so different from the `-la`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not "so different". `-h` is "human readable":

```
30777650366 -> 30056299K -> 29351M -> 28G for powers of 2
30777650366 -> 30777650K -> 30056M -> 30G for powers of 10
```

If you'd RTFM'd (`man ls`):

> ```
>   -h, --human-readable
>          with -l and/or -s, print human readable sizes (e.g., 1K 234M 2G)
>
>   --si   likewise, but use powers of 1000 not 1024
> ```

Comment: It's also worth noting that sizes are rounded, not truncated (the documentation doesn't seem to mention that).